# What do these icons in the Collection tab mean?

Tags: mesh, lighting, pose-mode

I'm trying to find information on the icons in the Collections tab in Blender:

[image]

Some of the icons (lights, pose, etc.) are self-explanatory, but the ones I've circled are unclear.  I have looked around SE and in the Blender manual, but I can't seem to find them, since I don't know what to call them in the first place.  What do they mean?

Comment: This is not a 1-1 reference but you can try looking through this

Comment: From top to bottom you have empty / armature / object / mesh, is it what you're trying to know?

Comment: I'd say "mesh object" rather than "object". Empties and armature are also objects, but with a different content.

Comment: Thank you.  I just didn't know what to call them, and now I do!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most common icons you'll see in the Outliner are also listed neatly in the *Add* menu (*Shift+A* in 3D view):

[image]

Looking at your screenshot, the circled ones respectively would be: an *Empty object*, an *Armature object*, a *Mesh object*, and a *mesh*. The orange color indicates that it is an [object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/scene_layout/object/introduction.html), whereas green ones represent *data-blocks*. You can think of an Object as a container that holds relevant data-blocks together. For instance, the "mat_body" object in your scene contains the "mat_body" mesh at the moment. They are named the same, but that doesn't mean they're the same thing: a mesh (a collection of vertices, edges and faces) is only one type of data-block that could be contained by an object. You could assign a material, an animation, or a modifier to that object, and all of them would be listed there with the mesh.

You can learn more about [data-blocks in the manual here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/data_blocks.html). Here's a full list of data-blocks available in Blender from that page:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.  I didn't know about the Add menu.  It's going to be a big help.

Comment: why can't the Blender devs just add tooltips to the icons?! Are we living in 2024, or 1924?